# What is the order of compilation between trait, class and case class/object

Tags: scala, class, object

What is the order of compilation for the following code? It seems to have a cyclic reference. The `trait List` requires the `object List` to be defined, the `object List` requires `case object Cons` to be defined which in turn requires the `trait List` to be defined. However, this still compiles.

```
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]

trait List[+A] {
    def create[A](x: A, t: List[A]) = List.make(x, t)
}

object List {
    def make[A](x: A, t: List[A]): List[A] = Cons(x, t) 
}
```

Comment: Does this have something to do with Scala reflection or do I need to go back and study how compiled languages work?

Comment: `trait List` does not depend on `object List` from a compilation standpoint. `trait List` can compile just fine without `object List`, as the singleton object is only required at *runtime* when the method `create` is called.

Comment: "Cyclic" (or forward) references to classes, traits and objects work fine and are a normal thing seen and used in Scala. You imagine the compiler being single pass, which it is not.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo thanks. That makes sense.

Comment: @Suma. TIL. Coming from mostly interpreted languages and Swift/Objective-C with ARC where circular references are mostly avoided (unless declared weak), this got me confused. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo No, `trait List` can't "compile just fine without `object List`" because it uses its method; if you removed `object List`, it wouldn't compile.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/297854/dependency-ordering-algorithm-of-a-compiler